# Rails not writing to development log

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My Rails app (version 4.0.3) is not logging anything in dev. My `development.log` (as well as `test.log`) were last touched on 12/12/2013, which is the day I created the project. So logging has evidently *never* worked in dev or test. (Production seems to be working just fine, FWIW.)

It doesn't seem to be a permissions issue; my log directory is recursively 777'd.

I've restarted my server after ensuring the permissions are good, so it's not that.

Any ideas?

Comment: did you check if anything logging in production.log? your app may working in production environment.

Comment: Yeah, logging is working perfectly fine in production.

Comment: when you start the server using `rails s`, what does it return?


If you run 
`rails s -e development -p 3002`
You should see something like: 

=> Booting Thin
=> Rails 3.2.14 application starting in `development` on http://0.0.0.0:3002
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
>> Thin web server (v1.5.1 codename Straight Razor)
>> Maximum connections set to 1024
>> Listening on 0.0.0.0:3002, CTRL+C to stop

Comment: @JasonSwett did you ever find a solution to this? Logging has stopped working in my Rails 4.2 app

Comment: No, I don't believe I ever did, sorry.

Comment: @JasonSwett Did you discover the problem? I'm having the same problem with a Rails app 4.0.1

Comment: No, it remains a mystery.

Comment: I had this issue when someone added `config.logger = ::Logger.new(STDOUT)` to `development.rb` which would obviously result into the logging no longer being written to the log file.

Comment: @tirdadc Thank you for your valuable comment.. My issue is fixed by it.